# C++/cli: How to convert String containing Bytes as characters to double

Tags: string, c++-cli, double, type-conversion

I have problem converting String^ containing 8 bytes as characters (as ascii) to double.
I want to take those 8 characters and convert them binary to double.

What would you recommend to do this conversion in C++/cli?

I was trying to use Marshal::Copy, Double::TryParse, etc.

Maybe I use wrong specifications of parameters, but I really lost my last hopes.
There must be something easy to do this conversion.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot store bytes in a System::String, Unicode normalization will destroy their values.

Comment: Your words do not make sense, SerialPort has an Encoding property.  Time to let your code do the talking, post a snippet that shows how your reading data from the port.

Comment: "Serious" solved it... but thanks for care ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the bad news is that the **System.String** class uses only **Unicode encoding** internally.

So if you give it bytes it will map them to its internal encoding hiding the original value.

The good news is that you can play with the **System.Text.Encoding** class to retrieve 8bits values corresponding to the unicode characters.

Here is a sample :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

int main()
{
    int n = 123456;
    double d = 123.456;

    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    char* n_as_bytes = (char*)&n;
    char* d_as_bytes = (char*)&d;

    String^ n_as_string = gcnew String(n_as_bytes, 0, sizeof(n));
    String^ d_as_string = gcnew String(d_as_bytes, 0, sizeof(d));

    Encoding^ ascii = Encoding::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

    array<Byte>^ n_as_array = ascii->GetBytes(n_as_string);
    array<Byte>^ d_as_array = ascii->GetBytes(d_as_string);

    cli::pin_ptr<unsigned char> pin_ptr_n = &n_as_array[0];
    cli::pin_ptr<unsigned char> pin_ptr_d = &d_as_array[0];

    unsigned char* ptr_n = pin_ptr_n;
    unsigned char* ptr_d = pin_ptr_d;

    int n_out = *(int*)ptr_n;
    double d_out = *(double*)ptr_d;

    std::cout << n_out << std::endl;
    std::cout << d_out << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This should give you :

```
123456
123.456
123456
123.456
```

Not sure it is completely safe, but trying it in your context should be a good start to ensure it is viable. :)

Comment: Thanks "Serious" your post was very helpful.

Comment: I have one more question ... Shouldn't be the memory that we point to deleted?

Comment: In the sample only managed memory is allocated so the objects will be garbage-collected automatically when (to be more precise : somewhere after) not used anymore.

Comment: That is what I want to hear :D